# Sticky Navbar Working in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, navbar

I've been searching for an answer to this all day, I think something is going wrong with other stylings but all the code I have works perfectly in Firefox but when in Chrome some weird things happen.

While scrolling down the page, at the point where the navbar should switch from under the header to fixed on top of the page, it will almost always jitter as the shift happens. Sometimes even flashing. Some things I've been able to replicate are :
A jump or flash anytime the shift happens.
A constant strobe flash if scrolled directly to the point of the change.
A slow and constant scroll will jump the page up about 5%.

Here's my code.

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />

        <title>NMU - SCA</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Student Cybersecurity Association</h1>
            <h2>of Northern Michigan University</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body {
    height:100%
}

#header {
    padding: 20%;
    background-color: black;
}

#header h1, #header h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.navbar {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: red;
}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

JQuery

```
var main = function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
     var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
      if ( scrollVal >= $('#header').outerHeight(true)) {
          $('.navbar').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});
      } else {
          $('.navbar').css({'position':'static','top':'auto'});
      }
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

I am really sick of this issue and just want chrome to behave.

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on Windows 10 and do not see the issue you are referring to. Perhaps it is the browser you are using? I see a smooth transition when the page scrolls and the nav is left.

Comment: I take that back. There is a smooth transition when using the scroll wheel on the mouse but not when I used the scroll bar on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick look and this seems to be working for me. I'll paste a code snippet below. The only change I made is the position static to absolute.

```
var main = function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( scrollVal >= $('#header').outerHeight(true)) {
            $('.navbar').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});
        } else {
            $('.navbar').css({'position':'absolute','top':'auto'});
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are the bomb.

Answer (score 0):

`.navbar` should be block, not `inline-block` and the `li`'s in `.navbar` can just be `inline-block` and don't need `float`. Seems to work if you take care of that.

Also changed your code a little to toggle a class instead of setting inline styles, but that isn't necessary to make this work in chrome.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop(),
      $header = $('#header'),
      $navbar = $('.navbar');
  if (scrollVal >= $header.outerHeight(true)) {
    $navbar.addClass("fixed");
  } else {
    $navbar.removeClass("fixed");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

#header {
  padding: 20%;
  background-color: black;
}

#header h1,
#header h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <h1>Student Cybersecurity Association</h1>
  <h2>of Northern Michigan University</h2>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If I could choose two answers I would here, because yours in congruence with the other answer is actually what made this all stop acting funny. Thanks so much for the reply! <3

Comment: @WolfNinja2 np :)